# Mysql is not fetching all the data

Tags: php, ajax

```
<?php
    include('config.php');

    $isd=mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['q'] );
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT zip FROM zipcod where abb='$isd' ") or ;


    while( $row=mysql_fetch_array( $sql, MYSQL_ASSOC ) ){
        $zip=$row['zip'];
        echo '<option>'.$zip.'</option> ';
    }
?>
```

This is the ajax

```
<script>
    function showUser(str) {
        if (str=="") {
            document.getElementById("zzips").innerHTML="";
            return;
        }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else { // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                document.getElementById("zzips").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getstate.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

HTML

```html
<select name="states"onchange="showUser(this.value)">
 <option value="AL">AL</option>
 <option value="AK">AK</option>
 <option value="AZ">AZ</option>
 <option>AR</option>
 <option>CA</option>
 <option>CO</option>
 <option>CT</option>
 <option>DE</option>
 <option>FL</option>
 <option>GA</option>
 <option>HI</option>
 <option>ID</option>
 <option>IL</option>
 <option>IN</option>
 <option>IA</option>
 <option>KS</option>
 <option>KY</option>
 <option>LA</option>
 <option>ME</option>
 <option>MD</option>
 <option>MA</option>
 <option>MI</option>
 <option>MN</option>
 <option>MS</option>
 <option>MS</option>
 <option>MT</option>
 <option>NE</option>
 <option>NV</option>
 <option>NH</option>
 <option>NJ</option>
 <option>NM</option>
 <option>NY</option>
 <option>NC</option>
 <option>ND</option>
 <option>OH</option>
 <option>OK</option>
 <option>OR</option>
 <option>PA</option>
 <option>RI</option>
 <option>SC</option>
 <option>SD</option>
 <option>TN</option>
 <option>TX</option>
 <option>UT</option>
 <option>VT</option>
 <option>VA</option>
 <option>WA</option>
 <option>WV</option>
 <option>WI</option>
 <option>WY</option>
</select>
```

This code is fetching Zip codes of some states like CO, NJ, not all. Can someone let me know the error so that it display zip codes according to the states selected in the first drop down

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a minor error in the php - you omit the condition after the `or` statement.

```
<?php
    include('config.php');

    $isd=trim( mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['q'] ) ); /* or? */
    /* Is the table actually called `zipcod` or `zipcode`? */
    $sql=mysql_query( "SELECT `zip` FROM `zipcod` where trim( `abb` )='$isd';" ) or die('bad mojo');


    while( $row=mysql_fetch_array( $sql, MYSQL_ASSOC ) ){
        $zip=$row['zip'];
        echo '<option>'.$zip.'</option> ';
    }
    mysql_free_result( $sql );

?>
```

To aid debugging javascript / ajax request:

```
function showUser(str) {
    var dbg=true;
    if( dbg )console.group('showUser');

    if( str=="" ) {
        document.getElementById("zzips").innerHTML="";
        if( dbg )console.warn('Empty string');
        return;
    }
    if( dbg )console.info( 'Initial value passed to ajax function: %s ',str );


    xmlhttp=window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    if( dbg )console.info( 'XHR Object created: %s', xmlhttp );

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if( xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200 ) {
            document.getElementById("zzips").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            if( dbg )console.info('Response received: %s', xmlhttp.responseText )
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open( "GET", "getstate.php?q="+str, true );
    if( dbg )console.info('Connection opened');

    xmlhttp.send();
    if( dbg )console.info('Request sent');
}
```

Comment: If you run the query manually in mysql or a gui such as Heidi do you get the results you expect for some of the states that are not returing results in php?

Comment: Yeah im not getting the values from other states. its only working on CO and NJ

Comment: I'd suggest then that if you are unable to get the results you expect when you run the query manally in a gui that the problem is with the data in the db. Can you confirm that the db does actually contain relevant data for the states that are causing issues?

Comment: Ok Thannks a lot .. Acctually the problem was that the states were in DB were stored with a white space ..Now i have to remove all the white space..

Comment: I edited the above to include `trim` which should help !

Comment: Well i used this code on my wordpress site but not working. mysql is working bt ajax not.. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I have just tested your ajax function and created a form with the dropdown of states with which to test - all seemed OK and I got the ajax callback to populate the `zzips` dropdown menu with returned response. Does the function `showUser` already exist? Is the function `showUser` invoked at all during the `onchange` call? Try putting some debug statements in the `showUser` function to see what is happening at various stages.

Comment: well its working fine but i think it not fetching data from getstate.php all though if i run the query manually it works.. DO you have some solution?

Answer (score 0):

**$sql=mysql_query("SELECT zip FROM zipcod where abb='$isd' ") or  ;**

Are you missing something here in your code as well or missed it while typing it again here? maybe you should have something like *or die("error message");* ?